# How to get first and second character from String in multiple conditions

Tags: java

I have name String[] let suppose "Raj Kumar". Then the condition is that I want to get "R" from Raj and "K" from "Kumar" and if the text is "Raj" then I have to get "Ra" from "Raj". How do I do that below is the code I want to modify.

code:-

```
public static final String[] titles = new String[]{"Raj", "Niraj Kumar"};
 for(int i = 0;i<titles.length;i++){
    char firstChar = titles[i].charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Is that the only condition?

Comment: yes...................if text is "Raj Kumar" then get "RK" and if text is "Raj" then get "Ra"

Comment: So is the input an array or a string? Is the input `"Raj Kumar"` or `{"Raj", "Kumar"}`?

Comment: only R and N....

Comment: See if String is "Raj" then i have to get RA and if String is "Raj Kumar" then i have to get "RK"

Comment: So you mean "for each item in the array, if the string is exactly 'Raj', transform that to 'Ra'. Otherwise transform that to the first character of the string"?

Comment: From for each loop if the String is "Raj" transfrom that to "Ra" and if the String is "Raj Kumar" transform that to "RK"

Comment: Okay, so if it has only one word, get the first two characters. If it has two words get the first character of each. Right? What happens if there are 3 words?

Comment: yes correct......if has 3 works then get first character of each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You this method

```
 public String getShortName(String name){
        String[] token=name.split(" ");

        if(token.length>1){
            String value="";
            for(int i=0;i<token.length;i++){
                value+=token[i].substring(0,1);
            }
            return value;
        }else{
           return token[0].length()>1?token[0].substring(0,2):token[0];
        }

    }
```

I have tested it, For array of names use this method in for loop

Comment: and how to print value

Comment: this method return value you can print it... in java System.out.println(getShortName("Raj")); OR  System.out.println(getShortName("Raj kumar"));

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
public static final String[] titles = new String[]{"Raj", "Niraj Kumar"};

    for(int i = 0;i<titles.length;i++){

        if(titles[i].contains(" ")){
           char firstChar = titles[i].charAt(0) + titles[i].split(" ")[1].charAt(0);
        }else{
           char firstChar = titles[i].charAt(0) + titles[i].charAt(1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please do it in only one variable

Comment: @Raj What do you mean one variable? One line?

Answer (score 0):

First, create this method to process each individual string in the array:

```
private static String processString(String string) {
    String[] words = string.split(" ");
    if (words.length == 1) {
        return words[0].substring(0, 2);
    } else {
        return Arrays.stream(words).map(x -> Character.toString(x.charAt(0))).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }
}
```

And then, stream the array and map each item using the method:

```
List<String> mapped = Arrays.stream(titles)
    .map(YourEnclosingClass::processString)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can then print the values out like this:

```
mapped.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String[] titles = new String[]{"Raj", "Niraj Kumar"};
        for (int i = 0;i<titles.length;i++){
            String shortChar;
            String[] nameSplit = titles[i].split("\\s+");
            if(nameSplit.length == 1) {
                shortChar = nameSplit[0].substring(0,2);
            } else {
                shortChar = nameSplit[0].substring(0,1) + nameSplit[1].substring(0,1);
            }
        }
```

Here you'll get **Ra** and **NK** as output (Hoping that the name contains first and second name only)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using stream API:

```
Arrays.stream(titles)
    .map(title -> title.contains(" ") ? 
        Arrays.stream(title.split(" "))
            .reduce("", (a, b) -> a + b.charAt(0)) :
        title.substring(0, 2))
    .forEach(result -> {
        // do with result
    });
```